# Passwords and Keys in Linux

Tags: linux, linux-mint

In a fit of desperation when I had my wireless connection die on me, I thought it was a problem with the key I had created at the start when I initially configured the wireless connection and hence deleted it. The option to create the key had presented itself when I created the wireless connection. It no longer asks me to.

Now I am back online, do I have re-create the password and key I had before? If so, what do I choose and why? The options I have are as follows;

1. PGP
2. Stored password
3. Password keyring
4. Secure shell key

The first and last option seem to be obvious and I have no idea about the differences between the second and third options.

Why do I need a stored password or password keyring in all scenarios and not just the wireless issue I ran into?

**EDIT 0**

Further to Belisama's comment, I have amended my question.

**EDIT 1**

As requested, I have attached a screenshot

[image]

Comment: You should consider adding the word "wireless" to the title and also one or more of the "wireless" tags. I came to the question expecting it to be about passwords and keys in Linux _in general_.

Comment: @M Barrett - The reason I didn't add wireless to the title or the tags is because I wanted to understand its application in all scenarios including wireless.

Comment: Ah, in that case, you might want to reword your question a bit. It read to me as though you were just trying to solve a specific problem with your wireless configuration. Even just leading with "For example . . . " would make it clearer.

Comment: @Belisama - Thanks. Have amended my question with additional details in the last paragraph.

Comment: This is distribution / desktop environment specific.  Please post a screenshot of what you are seeing and add the distribution and DE to the tags

Comment: @Paul- I have amended the question with a screenshot.

Comment: It would probably still help to tag with your distribution and desktop environment.

Comment: @Eroen - Have tagged the post and the desktop environment is Gnome. The version of Linux Mint I have installed are both 11 and 12 however the screenshot is specific to 12.

Answer (score 1):

The "password keyring" one is if you have an app that requires security, so you can give it a password, the password will be added to the "keyring" and you unlock all of the passwords on the "Keyring" by typing a password into the dialog box after you've logged into the system. That's how I understand it, anyway.

In brief: "for convenience"

Comment: I remember this when I used gnome, but my mum's KDE enviroment does the same.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for being a newbie here but if I walk through a scenario, it might make it easier for me to follow. So let's that I am using Skype. It requires me to log in. Does that qualify as an application that requires security? If yes, I enter my password to log into Skype. Does it then store this password in the key ring? What do you mean by `unlock all of the passwords on the "Keyring" by typing a password into the dialog box after you've logged into the system`?

Comment: no worrys, we were all there once ;)

Comment: uh, yes skype qualify's (I think :P) 

"Does it then store this password in the key ring?" Only if it prompts you to, It's normally just on system wireless and such... 

"What do you mean by unlock all of the passwords on the "Keyring" by typing a password into the dialog box after you've logged into the system?"

It unlocks all of the system passwords (ie, it logs you in to wireless) by providing a dialog box that you type a master password (but not the root password) into.

err :/ :confused: :P have you tried looking at the documentation???

Comment: What is the difference between a system and a master password?

Comment: the master password is the one you choose for the keyring, the system passwords are like the one for your wireless, etc...